# RPC synchronisation issues

Tags: rpc, node

I'm currently running rpc node with the following config:

```
exec solana-validator \
--identity /home/ubuntu/validator-keypair.json \
--known-validator 7Np41oeYqPefeNQEHSv1UDhYrehxin3NStELsSKCT4K2 \
--known-validator GdnSyH3YtwcxFvQrVVJMm1JhTS4QVX7MFsX56uJLUfiZ \
--known-validator DE1bawNcRJB9rVm3buyMVfr8mBEoyyu73NBovf2oXJsJ \
--known-validator CakcnaRDHka2gXyfbEd2d3xsvkJkqsLw2akB3zsN1D2S \
--full-rpc-api \
--no-voting \
--ledger /mnt/ledger \
--accounts /mnt/accounts \
--log /home/ubuntu/solana-validator.log \
--rpc-port 8899 \
--dynamic-port-range 8000-8020 \
--entrypoint entrypoint.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
--entrypoint entrypoint2.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
--entrypoint entrypoint3.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
--entrypoint entrypoint4.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
--entrypoint entrypoint5.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
--expected-genesis-hash 5eykt4UsFv8P8NJdTREpY1vzqKqZKvdpKuc147dw2N9d \
--wal-recovery-mode skip_any_corrupted_record \
--limit-ledger-size
```

However, every 4 hours it start to download snapshot from other node, which I assume is because is loses some slots during synchronisation.

```
[2024-03-30T07:44:51.882707971Z INFO  solana_validator::bootstrap] RPC node root slot: 257309276
[2024-03-30T07:44:51.884484538Z INFO  solana_validator::bootstrap] Local snapshot from slot 257292009 is too old. Downloading a newer snapshot for slot 257308951.
[2024-03-30T07:44:51.884547543Z INFO  solana_runtime::snapshot_utils] Purging old full snapshot archives in /mnt/ledger, retaining up to 2 full snapshots
[2024-03-30T07:44:51.885032010Z INFO  solana_runtime::snapshot_utils] Purging old incremental snapshot archives in /mnt/ledger, retaining up to 4 incremental snapshots
[2024-03-30T07:44:52.270161236Z INFO  solana_download_utils] Downloading 67571500629 bytes from http://139.84.229.211:8899/snapshot-257293271-GeEhdmPUu5juTQE6C2qSWVdKTtj3BaGn2kxn8Z2zn1Hi.tar.zst
```

Why is the happening and how it can be resolved? Because during download, node is not operational

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve this via increasing cpu GHz from 2.5 to 3.7